# Visual studio Symfony lineas de error

Tags: php, mysql, html5, visual-studio, symfony

Sé que el error proviene de la extensión de Symfony para vscode, pero no sé cómo resolverlo.

Hola, estoy usando Visual Studio para crear una aplicación web Symfony. Estuve trabajando unos días y todo fue normal. Pero hoy no sé por qué cuando entro dentro del proyecto me muestra líneas en color rojo, y un mensaje que dice que:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resolví este error con esta línea en setting.json:

```
"symfony-vscode.phpExecutablePath": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe"
```

Pero las líneas rojas se quedan ahí y la ejecución del programa funciona perfecto, lo único son las líneas rojas, mira:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sé que el error proviene de la extensión de Symfony para vscode, pero no sé cómo resolverlo.

Comment: Las líneas rojas lo que indican es que el VS Code no pudo encontrar esos métodos en la clase, o no encuentra la clase que los contiene. Tal vez te falte importar la clase AbstractController

Comment: El problema es que si que las encuentra, a la hora de ejecutarlo y todo. Llevo usándolo ya tiempo y han aparecido mágicamente en algunas que no aparecían antes.

Answer (score 0):

He vuelto a mirar en el proyecto y he encontrado estos errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto deberías ponerlo en la pregunta, edita la pregunta y añade esto. Y borra esta respuesta. Porque si lo pones como respuesta todos van a pensar que encontraste la solución y no te van a responder ;-) Saludos.